# Fastlogging inside Airflow

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I am currently using airflow heavily for speed-sensitive scripts.
I am trying to log much information up to 100Klines/sec.

The default logging library is working but too slow.
My current set up:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")
logger.info('.. start logging information')
```

I would like to use faslogging library (https://github.com/brmmm3/fastlogging) which is at least 5X faster:

```
from fastlogging import LogInit
logger = LogInit(pathName="example1.log")
logger.info(".. start logging information fast")
```

My issue is that I still want to use all the nice formatting from airflow as well as the automatic backup to S3.
To do that I need use a function similar to getLogger("airflow.task") and don't have to give a pathName to LogInit.

```
from fastlogging import GetLogger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = GetLogger("airflow.task")
    logger.debug("This is a debug message.")
    logger.rotate()
    logger.fatal("This is a fatal message.")
    logger.shutdown()
Warning: airflow.task: LogInit should be called first!

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-49874f7d5ab0> in <module>
      2 
      3 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 4     logger = GetLogger()
      5     logger.debug("This is a debug message.")
      6     logger.rotate()

fastlogging/fastlogging.pyx in fastlogging.fastlogging.GetLogger()

fastlogging/fastlogging.pyx in fastlogging.fastlogging.Logger.__init__()

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in dirname(p)
    154 def dirname(p):
    155     """Returns the directory component of a pathname"""
--> 156     p = os.fspath(p)
    157     sep = _get_sep(p)
    158     i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Also, LogInit without a filename:

```
from fastlogging import LogInit
logger = LogInit()
logger.info(".. start logging information fast")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d749b56426d4> in <module>
      1 from fastlogging import LogInit
----> 2 logger = LogInit()
      3 logger.info(".. start logging information fast")

fastlogging/fastlogging.pyx in fastlogging.fastlogging.LogInit()

fastlogging/fastlogging.pyx in fastlogging.fastlogging.GetLogger()

fastlogging/fastlogging.pyx in fastlogging.fastlogging.Logger.__init__()

/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in dirname(p)
    154 def dirname(p):
    155     """Returns the directory component of a pathname"""
--> 156     p = os.fspath(p)
    157     sep = _get_sep(p)
    158     i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Did anyone try that or would know how to do it? I have no resource a part https://www.astronomer.io/guides/logging which is not enough

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @Malo, I added some code and information. I hope it is helpful.